# unattended install of binary python packages (modules) for windows

Tags: python, windows, setuptools

Is there no sane way to peform a scripted install of binary python packages for windows? Unfortunately it seems like several essential windows python packages like pywin32 and py2exe are only available as EXE's not MSI's (and as far as I know only the latter are scriptable). Easy_install/pip also seems no use since they apparently only find source packages and then try to compile locally which is obviously unsatisfactory.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download the source code of pywin32 at [sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) and then build it as MSI file yourself. Therefore you need setuptools (only for building). Use the command "setup.py bdist_msi" to create a MSI installer in the "dist" directory.

The same procedure should work for all Windows-compatible packages.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this seems the best approach. I'm baffled that almost no python project provides msis since as far as I can tell they are strictly and significantly superior to exe installers.

Comment: This thread provides information about how to get `python setup.py bdist_msi` to work for pywin32: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2013-June/012851.html

Answer (score 7):

Current easy_install can install the pre-build ".exe" installers silently, i.e.;

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe pywin32-220.win32-py2.7.exe
```

will install pywin32.

This also enables possibility to remove using pip;

```
pip uninstall pywin32 -y
```

uninstalls pywin32

Answer (score 2):

As said in [a linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485932/47407) you can succeed with using `easy_install` if the installer was created with [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want scripted automation of installs on Windows, look into AutoIt.