# unattended install of python module .exe files

Tags: python, distribute

I'm looking for a way to install a bunch of python modules in `.exe` format like:

```
ipython-0.13.1.py2-win32-PROPER.exe
scipy-0.12.0b1.win32-py2.7.exe
numpy-MKL-1.7.0.win32-py2.7.exe
pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe
```

I can install other modules by installing `distribute` and call pip from command-line, but I want to know if I can automate installs of .exe files - so users don't have to click buttons of 'next' 'okay'.

Comment: As you can imagine this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3044359/42346 Maybe something has changed since then..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, this is indeed possible:

I used distribute's `easy_install` and everything worked like a magic.

just use `easy_install [exeinstaller1] [exeinstaller2] ...`

Comment: This will just work if the installer is a distutils exe. A failing example is the [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) installer.